# How to migrate Documents from SP 2010 on premise to O365 and keep the Document ID

Tags: document-migration

We've been using the Document ID feature on our on premise 2010 farm. We use the generated Document ID and make sure the value is placed on the front page of the documents.

Now we're going to migrate this site collection to O365. It is important that we keep the Document ID for all documents and ensures that all new documents created in the O365 farm get unique Document ID values. I'm thinking that I can use a different prefix to avoid duplicate id's. The remaining problem is to migrate the content with Document ID to O365.

I've looked at different migration tools, and some sales persons tell me they support this in migration, but so far none of them can show me that it works the way I need to. I don't want to get the Document ID value to a new text column, I need to get the value into the Document ID column.

Does anyone know if this is possible and if any of the migration tools actually support this peroperly? We have a lot of documents and are not looking for a free solution, I just don't want to buy licenses to a product that can't migrate Document ID properly.

Regards
ElinK

Comment: Can you get an evaluation license for a migration tool and just test it out? Most SharePoint content migration tools promise full fidelity migration and I would imagine that would include document IDs. When in doubt, verify it for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the Migration tool does keep the document ID intact while migration. I had used ShareGate tool for the migration of my documents and sites and it worked perfectly

http://en.share-gate.com/blog/sharegate-release-4-6-migrate-sharepoint-document-id